# Change background color in launch screen when using DayNight theme

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

I am using **DayNight** theme with **launch screen**.

Launch screen is a layer-list with white background.

So when its day, **white** launch screen shows followed by **white** activity. But at night, **white** launch screen shows follwed by **dark** activity.

*How can i change the background color in the launch screen according to the theme.*

Cannot use custom color attrs because there is only a DayNight theme.

**themes.xml**

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlNormal">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="LaunchTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_screen</item>
</style>
```

**launch_screen.xml**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <color android:color="@color/material_white"/>
</item>
<item>
    <bitmap
       android:gravity="center"
       android:src="@drawable/launch_logo"
       android:tileMode="disabled"/>
</item>
```

Comment: Read this you will get some Idea : http://blog.nkdroidsolutions.com/android-daynight-theme-example-using-appcompat-v23-2/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link. Didn't knew about drawable-night and values-night folders. This will do :)

Comment: Well unfortunately, night qualifiers does not work with launch screens. Because launch screen is loaded by OS, not the app. :(

Comment: Yes, but If you change `android:windowBackground` in `styles` it is succeeds changing splash background. The problem is that `DayNight` mode is not changed until startup. Since it's a dynamic thing (Can be changed based on Preference).

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In addition to your default launch theme provide its night variant in appropriate resource directory.

#### res/values-night/themes.xml

```
<style name="LaunchTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_screen_night</item>
</style>
```

#### res/drawable/launch_screen_night.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <color android:color="@color/material_black"/>
</item>
<item>
    <bitmap
       android:gravity="center"
       android:src="@drawable/launch_logo"
       android:tileMode="disabled"/>
</item>
```

Comment: Tried this solution. In my case I still couldn't get desired mode background color on splash screen. As explained here(https://cyrilmottier.com/2013/01/23/android-app-launching-made-gorgeous/), Android using Zygote trick to show Preview Window. And background color for this window is set by default app theme that is set in Manifest for Application.

Comment: Application can't load night theme for 1-2 second when first launch.

Comment: Yeah, this only works if you have a special launch activity and it launches quickly (no heavy code in your Application class). The day/night "preview theme" should work on Android 10 as if local night mode was set to "follow system".

Answer (score 5):

After checking for a while, I found answer.

Since splash screen configuration is loaded by system, you will need to affect system UI mode.

```
getSystemService<UiModeManager>()?.nightMode = UiModeManager.MODE_NIGHT_YES
```

But unfortunately this is not clean solution, since it affects system settings.

> Changes to night mode take effect globally and will result in a
>   configuration change (and potentially an Activity lifecycle event)
>   being applied to all running apps. Developers interested in an
>   app-local implementation of night mode should consider using
>   AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(int) to manage the -night
>   qualifier locally.

Comment: Well, I guess no more splash screen for me.